# Retrieving a flat result - BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, flatten

I have the following standard SQL query in bigQuery:

```
SELECT
    Chr,
    start_position,
    reference_bases,
    call.name,
    call.genotype,
    alternate_bases.alt,
    alternate_bases_CSQ_VT.*
FROM
    `mutable`,
    UNNEST(call) AS call,
    UNNEST(call.genotype) AS genotype,
    UNNEST(alternate_bases) AS alternate_bases,
    UNNEST(alternate_bases.CSQ_VT) AS alternate_bases_CSQ_VT
WHERE
    call.name = "sample name"
    AND CLIN_SIG = "pathogenic"
    AND genotype > 0
LIMIT
  100
```

The table that is returned is flat, except for the resulting genotype field (for which there are two records for each line returned). I would like to return a flat table where the two genotype values for each line are converted to two new columns (allele 1 and allele 2) but am struggling with the correct approach. Any pointers would be great

[image: table result]

Comment: I don't understand your data structure or query.  Your query has a column called `name`, not in the sample results.  You have a `where` clause that would filter out genotype 0, but that is in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to follow.  Often, the best approach is a subquery using `UNNEST()`.  I can't quite figure out your data model (and the query and sample data are not consistent).  But, something like this:

```
SELECT . . . ,
       (SELECT MAX(call.name)
        FROM UNNEST(call) genotype
        WHERE call.genotype = 0
       ) as genotype_0,
       (SELECT MAX(call.name)
        FROM UNNEST(call) genotype
        WHERE call.genotype = 1
       ) as genotype_1
FROM `mutable`,
     UNNEST(alternate_bases) AS alternate_bases,
     UNNEST(alternate_bases.CSQ_VT) AS alternate_bases_CSQ_VT
WHERE call.name = 'sample name'
      CLIN_SIG = 'pathogenic'
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answer I will try this also - apologies that the question wasn't too clear. I did come up with a solution, although I have no idea if it is efficient.

```
SELECT
  Chr,
  start_position,
  reference_bases,
  call.name,
  call.genotype[OFFSET(0)] as all1,
  call.genotype[OFFSET(1)] as all2,
  alternate_bases.alt,
  alternate_bases_CSQ_VT.*
FROM
  `mutable`,
  UNNEST(call) AS call,
  UNNEST(call.genotype) AS genotype,
  UNNEST(alternate_bases) AS alternate_bases,
  UNNEST(alternate_bases.CSQ_VT) AS alternate_bases_CSQ_VT
WHERE
  call.name = "sample name"
  AND CLIN_SIG = "pathogenic"
  AND genotype > 0
LIMIT
  100
```